# PHP count 3 of var and remove 3+

Tags: php, laravel, count

i hope the title already explains what i'm looking for here. 
I'm using laravel and having a hard time to get only 3 object returned.

Im getting an object which contains several posts. I want to output only 3 of these objects and leave the rest out.

I'm using this a.t.m. but this isn't working since it isn't a array i'm getting.

```
    @if(count($posts) >= '3')
        <?php array_splice($posts, 3); ?>
    @endif
```

I know Laravel has the paginate function build in, but this sometimes returns only 2 or 1 or 4, never the right amount.

print_r $posts

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => Digitus\Base\Model\Post Object ( [fillable:protected] => Array ( [0] => title [1] => body [2] => author [3] => slug [4] => image [5] => metatitle [6] => metadescription [7] => robots [8] => ogtitle [9] => ogdescription [10] => ogsitename [11] => ogurl [12] => ogimage [13] => ogtype [14] => concept ) [connection:protected] => [table:protected] => [primaryKey:protected] => id [perPage:protected] => 15 [incrementing] => 1 [timestamps] => 1 [attributes:protected] => Array ( [id] => 15 [concept] => 0 [title] => Hoe Je Kunt Zien Wanneer Je Fans Online Zijn En Hoe Je Hier Eenvoudig Op Inspeelt Om Zo Veel Mogelijk Fans Te Bereiken. [body] =>
```

Comment: If `$posts` isn't an array what is it?

Comment: it's an object, in it is an array containing all posts. So i have to get passed the object..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're all way ahead of yourselves, if you only want 3, don't grab them all and then only display 3, just grab 3.

```
Posts::where('blargh', 'honk')->take(3);
```

I assume you're using the `get()` method on your model to return a collection, instead replace that with the `take()` method which will add a `limit` to the query. Obviously you'll need to add your ordering etc, but this is the proper way to do it, at the query end, not the view end.

Comment: Ok great thanks, i'll test that in a minute. 

PS. am i also able to do this when getting the posts from a category? with many-to-many relation

Comment: Well, using the following:

$cats= Categorie::where('name','=',$categorie->name)->first();
$posts = $cats->posts()->take(3);

Doesn't work. Is there a different approach to this or .. ?

Answer (score 1):

The [docs on the collection object](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Support.Collection.html#methods) you have show that there is a slice method so this should work:

```
    @if(count($posts) >= '3')
        <?php $posts->slice(3); ?>
    @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dirty solution:

```
<?php $i = 0;?>
@foreach($posts as $post)
    <?php $i++; if($i==4) break;?>
    {{ $post->title }}
@endif
```

Comment: @Jeroen you should check out Jim's answer - it's more correct to the framework, and much less dirty.

Comment: That's horrendous, why on earth would you do this?

Comment: I agree with you guys, Jim's answer is clean, I just did a quick solution. Good to know there is slice method

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to grab the first or last 3, `take` should work.

```
@foreach($posts->take(3) as $post)
    {{ $post->title }}
@endforeach
```

But if you only need 3 of something from the start you would want to limit that at the source as ollieread has mentioned.

Ref: 
[Support\Collection@take](http://laravel.com/api/4.1/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_take)

`public function take($limit = null)` "Take the first or last {$limit} items."

Answer (score -1):

Try this one-> You are using Wrong syntax.

```
if(count($posts) >= 3):
        <?php array_splice($posts, 3); ?>
    endif;
```

Comment: He is using laravels blade template-engine. i guess, beacuse he has laravel as a tag.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, but it's the same :)

+ i'm looking for an alternative for array_splice since i'm getting an object returned with all the posts in it.

Comment: `print_r($posts) ` and post here to better understanding.